# Webpack use both css module and import entire css file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

In my react app, I have a [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) config file that is changing the [localIdentName](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname) of css classes in my application. I use this setup so that I can import css as a module into my react components - this functionality works fine. However, I am using a js/npm library that requires I import the css for the component (React app) directly. I **must** use `import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";` and cannot import the css any other way.

To facilitate this, I need (or would think) to add another rule in my Webpack config. My existing rule that handles my css files is below:

```
      // Pipe other styles through css modules and append to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

I propose that I need a new rule to accommodate adding `react-day-picker/lib/style.css`, however adding such rule **before** my existing rule does not seem to match the file (my existing/original/first rule picks up `react-day-picker/lib/style.css` instead).

```
      // just for day picker
      {
        test: /\/react-day-picker\/lib\/style\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              // NOTE - no modules: true here!
              localIdentName: '[local]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

1. Are the order of rules in the Webpack config the same order Webpack looks for files?
2. How can I modify my rules such that Webpack picks up my file (`react-day-picker/lib/style.css`) and allows it to be imported?

Answer (score 0):

The updated set of rules in order to load my existing css as modules, but this libraries' css file as a regular css import is as follows:

```
      // just for day picker
      {
        test: /react-day-picker.*style\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              localIdentName: '[local]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      // Pipe other styles through css modules and append to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

I believe my earlier code was not working because I needed to properly exclude the **node_modules** directory (it wasn't enough to simply rely on a [rule's test property](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) to include the libraries' css file.) Once I had that rule exclude the node_modules folder, I had trouble actually including the libraries' **style.css** file (it *might* have been because I was prefixing the property with a forward slash /